# XQuery - Equivalent to SQL NOT IN

Tags: xml, xquery

I have a query in SQL, and I'd like to understand how to do an equivalent query with XQuery.

```
SELECT S.name
FROM SCHOOL AS S
WHERE S.name NOT IN (
SELECT S1.name 
FROM SCHOOL AS S1, KID AS K
WHERE S1.county <> k.county AND S1.name = k.school_name
)
```

This query finds the schools that only serve students who live in the same county as the school is located. Now, here's what I think the equivalent query would look like in XQuery:

```
for
$p in /Schools/School
where
not($p/Name = ( for 
$s in /Schools/School
$k in /Kids/Kid
where
not($s/County = $k/County)
and $s/Name = $k/School_name
return $s/Name )
) 
return $p/Name
```

I am unsure if what I did here is legal syntax, and if it achieves the desired result. Am I allowed to nest XQuery queries like I did? And will the first where condition in the XQuery statement work?

If the XQuery that I wrote doesn't work, how do you achieve similar results to SQL's NOT IN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that, but it seems very convoluted. Does the following look right to you?

```
for $p in /Schools/School
where every $k in /Kids/Kid[School_name = $p/Name] 
      satisfies $k/County = $p/County
return $p/Name
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm looking for, thanks for the help!